# Server performance issue - which query will be better solution

Tags: php, mysql

I have this simple question about server performance.
Let say that I generate $_SESSION['expired_products'] which is array of ids of all products that:

```
$query='select id from products 
where active="1" and available_qty > 0 and expired_date > now()';
```

this query will be executed on first visitor's visit

and than query in a loop will check:

```
$query='select * from products where id not in('.$_SESSION['expired_products'].')';
```

Or each time to check for: 
active="1" and available_qty > 0 and expired_date > now()

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would probably be better to do the check each time, because you don't know when quantity will become 0, could be 10 seconds, could be never.  Also expired_date could be soon, though this issue could be somewhat mitigated by adding some time to now().

Make sure active, available_qty, and expired_date have indexes in the database.  With indexes, performance most likely won't be an issue.

As far as performance with the queries,

```
$query='select id from products 
where active="1" and available_qty > 0 and expired_date > now()';
```

is considerabaly faster than

```
$query='select * from products where id not in('.$_SESSION['expired_products'].')';
```

if you have a lot of expired products, though IN is considerably faster than chaining OR's together.

Comment: Xeridea, I have solved this problem with additional checks when user try to order the specific product.. Iam asking general for the performance !

Comment: @Europeuser Ok, I would just make sure searched fields are indexed, you can do multiple where conditions on a table with thousands of rows in under 1 ms if things are indexed properly.

Comment: indexing fields in not necessary if i search in not in('.$_SESSION['expired_products'].') ?

Comment: @Europeuser Indexes aren't totally necessary if you have a small dataset (like less than 100 rows), but it is good practice to at least index the primary field, which is generally the id field.